# Como fazer um Submenu na Action Bar?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, submenu

Surgiu uma necessidade de criar um `menu` com `submenu` na `action bar`, igual a este:

[image: Menu e submenu]

Poderiam me ajudar?

Meu `XML` menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:apk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_atualizar"
    android:title="@string/menu_atualizar"
    apk:showAsAction="ifRoom"
 />
</menu>
```

Meu código:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);      
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_atualizar:
        //código aqui...
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para ter um submenu, você deve ter um menu dentro de um menu. Utilizando XML Desta forma:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/file"
          android:icon="@drawable/file"
           android:title="@string/file"
           apk:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
     >
        <!-- submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_atualizar"
                  android:title="Form 1"
                  />
            <item android:id="@+id/form_2"
                  android:title="Form 2" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

No seu exemplo você apenas tem um menu, e não um menu dentro de um menu(submenu).

Java:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handler dos cliques em cada menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_atualizar:
            //codigo
        case R.id.form_2:
            //codigo
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## [Referência do Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#submenu)

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o nome disso não é submenu, mas apenas menu. Para criá-lo em seu código atual é apenas questão de adicionar uma ou mais linhas [menu.add()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) como abaixo:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);      
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 0, R.string.form1);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 1, R.string.form2);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somente complementando o que já foi respondido.

Esse "sub-menu" é criado automaticamente pelo ActionBar e o que vai determinar se vai aparecer ou não o sub-menu são as seguintes regras;

- Botões de ação no bar principal ação não pode ocupar mais de 50% da
  largura da barra. Os botões de acção sobre barras de ação do fundo
  pode usar toda a largura.
- A largura da tela em pixels independentes de densidade ( dp )
  determinar o número de itens que se encaixam na principal barra de
  ação:

  1. menor do que 360 ​​dp = 2 ícones
  2. 360-499 dp = 3 ícones
  3. 500-599 dp = 4 ícones
  4. 600 dp e = 5 maiores ícones

Como podemos verificar se voce utiliza um Nexus S e coloca 2 icones, não ira aparecer o sub-menu, porem se colocar 3 ou mais o sub-menu ira aparecer automaticamente.

[Fonte e mais informações](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

Comment: Entendi, valeo (: